# Formulate and Prove by induction a general formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$1^3=1$

$2^3=3+5$

$3^3=7+9+11$

$4^3=13+15+17+19$

Please help me to find the formula. I have no idea about this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:logic]?

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^nn^2-n-1+2i=n^3$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Before you find an explicit formula, it's helpful just to look for patterns. Here, consider that all of the numbers are odd. If you find a pattern, edit your post to indicate this.

Comment: How many terms are there on the right-hand side?  How does that relate to the left-hand side?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: notice that the terms that appear on the RHS are all the sums of odd numbers. Try and use this to come up with a formula.

Answer (score -1):

Hint

Alternative approach that avoids using induction.

Each expression $n^3 = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots a_k$ 
involves exactly $n$ terms (i.e. $k = n$), whose average value is $n^2.$

Of course, proving that the average value of these terms is $n^2$, may involve induction, or may also be proven directly.